# SSH - known_hosts file generation content behavior

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, sshd

When is executed

```
ssh -i id_rsa_something remoteuser@192.168.1.2
```

appears:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ABCABC [fixed/changed].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

If I write yes I can get access to the remote server through SSH. So until here the SSH configuration for remote connections works as expected. Furthermore in the `.ssh/known_hosts` file, in the *client*, was added:

```
192.168.1.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNo...
```

Now, if I delete the `known_hosts` file and re-execute the first command, the same behaviour happens - but in this case the `known_hosts` file is re-created with only the new *"record"* expected. Until all is ok.

Now, if again the `known_hosts` file (*client* side) is deleted and then the following events are executed:

- The `ssh-agent` is started
- The `ssh-add` is executed for a specific private key (`id_rsa_something`) - the passphrase is requested

is possible get the connection to the remote server, but the `known_hosts` file is not re-created and of course the new *record* does not exist because was not added

**Question 1**

Why the latter approach does not re-create the `known_hosts` file and add the new record? or if the `known_hosts` file already exists why was not added the expected record?

**Question 2**

Why that behavior?

**Question 3**

So about the use of the `known_hosts` file - when is mandatory use an approach over the other?

Comment: I wonder what happens with `~/.ssh/known_hosts.old` when doing these experiments.

Comment: No backup because the content for the `known_hosts` file is only for GitHub and few PCs for a small LAN - it is a for an isolated LAN